# How to load data from 2 json files using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have two json files and I want to do an ajax call to both of them.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contest_media', function(data) { do something });
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contest', function(data) { do something });
```

I want it to become something like:

```
$.getJSON(['http://www.example.com/contest_media', 'http://www.example.com/contest'], function(data) { do something});
```

I am also using `$.each(data, function(i,item) {}` so I can't do:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contests', function(data) { 
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
    do something
    $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contest_media', function(data) {do something });
}
});
```

Here the `contest_media` won't keep track of `contests`.

I basically want to use data from both json files in the same `$.each`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this can be done with `$.when`. In your case your code would probably look something like...

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contest_media'),
    $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/contest')
).done(function(contestMedia, contest) {

    // do something    
    // contestMedia = [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ]
    // contest = [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ]

    // response data can be gotten with contest[2].responseText

});
```

[jQuery doc page for $.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when)

Note that this requires jQuery version 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just nest it? I imagine you need to rely on data from both of them anyhow.

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/contest_media', function(data) {
 // do basic stuff
 $.getJSON('http://example.com/contest', function(data) {
   // do more stuff now that you have both pieces of data
 });
});
```

Comment: i tried that but i am using `$.each(data, function(i,item) {}` for the `contest_media` ... and it will ont keep track of the `contests`

Comment: might want to post a bit more code? sounds like a scoping issue.

Comment: i basically want to use values from both json files into one html

Comment: I find nesting unreadable, also it quickly leads to "callback hell"